# Remove grayscale TabWidget border/edge

Tags: android, tabs

I have a custom Tab Indicator to make my tabs.  However, I want to remove the bottom border below the tab.  Both the single black line, and the greyscale shadow.  I'm not even sure what is generating the greyscale fade.  It's possibly TabWidget, FrameLayout, or the children's LinearLayout.

[image]

For reference, I've tried setStripEnabled(false);
Another potential difficulty is that I'm creating the TabHost & TabWidget programmatically rather than using a layout file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use tabs, I normally just hide the tabwidget tag by setting android visibility as gone.

And add buttons to act as the tab buttons like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">       
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="64dip">
                <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" 
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_tab_artists" 
                    android:id="@+id/artist_id" android:onClick="tabHandler"/>
                <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" 
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_tab_artists" 
                    android:id="@+id/album_id" android:onClick="tabHandler"/>
                <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip"     
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_tab_artists" 
                    android:id="@+id/song_id" android:onClick="tabHandler"/>
            </LinearLayout> 
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and I add a button click handler

```
public void tabHandler(View target){
    artistButton.setSelected(false);
    albumButton.setSelected(false);
    songButton.setSelected(false);
    if(target.getId() == R.id.artist_id){
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
        artistButton.setSelected(true);
    } else if(target.getId() == R.id.album_id){
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        albumButton.setSelected(true);
    } else if(target.getId() == R.id.song_id){
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
        songButton.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

This should remove all the lines and grayscale.